# Como hago para agregar una condición mas en mi consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

En la consulta estoy filtrando la tabla citaciones por grado, pero ahora deseo filtrarlo tambien por sección, es decir por grado y sección como hago para agregar ese criterio.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnconsulta2']))$btnconsulta2=$_POST['btnconsulta2'];
    if($btnconsulta2)
    {
        require_once 'conexion.php';    
        $GRADO=$_POST["xGRADO"];
        $sql = "SELECT asunto, contenido, grado, seccion, seccion, fecha_envio, fecha_citacion, reportado  FROM CITACIONES WHERE grado='" .$GRADO. "'";
        //$sql="SELECT * from CITACIONES";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        ?>
        <table name="tabla" align="center" border="1" >
        <tr>
            
            <td>ASUNTO</td>
            <td>CONTENIDO</td>
            <td>GRADO</td>
            <td>SECCION</td>    
            <td>FECHA DE ENVIO</td> 
            <td>FECHA DE CITACION</td>  
            <td>REPORTADO</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 

        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['asunto'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['contenido'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['grado'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['seccion'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_envio'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['fecha_citacion'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['reportado'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    }
     ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes establecer dos condiciones separadas por un operador **`AND`** para indicar que buscas resultados en esta consulta cuando ambas condiciones se cumplan quedando así:

```
WHERE grado='" .$GRADO. "' 
  AND seccion = '" .$SECCION. "'....
```

Observaciones

- Si alguna de las dos condiciones no se cumple entonces **no obtendrás datos de vuelta**
- Debería trabajar con consultas preparadas y no pasar lo que el usuario manda directo al cuerpo de la consulta

**Fuentes**

- [Operadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)
- [Consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hola simplemente debes condicionar la consulta con los operadoras (AND OR) y estos se encargaran de hacer la consulta con diferentes parámetros
En tu caso seria.

```
 $sql = "SELECT *   FROM CITACIONES WHERE grado='" .$GRADO. "' AND seccion='" .$SECCION. "' ";
```